# Tabular: Aligning cell content on the top left (including an image)

Tags: tables, graphics, alignment, cell

I am having trouble aligning the contents of the cells in a table in the upper left corner. The problem seems to be caused by the SVG file, since everything works fine without it. Also, once I'm introducing `makecell` for vertical alignment, the automatic linebreak seems to go sideways, too.

[image: bad table]

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{extarticle}

\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular*}{16cm}{p{3cm} p{4cm} p{9cm}}
      \hline
      \makecell[tl]{\includesvg[width=2.5cm]{assets/ERROR_Battery.svg}} & \makecell[tl]{\textbf{Battery Error}} & \makecell[tl]{This error code indicates that there is a problem with the battery and/or the charging electronics.}\\
      \hline
      \makecell[tl]{img here} & \makecell[tl]{\textbf{GNSS Error}} & \makecell[tl]{This error code indicates that there is a problem communicating with the GNSS module.}\\
      \hline
      \makecell[tl]{img here} & \makecell[tl]{\textbf{IMU Error}} & \makecell[tl]{This error code indicates that there is a problem communicating with either one or both of the inertial measurement units.}\\
      \hline
      \makecell[tl]{img here} & \makecell[tl]{\textbf{WiFi Error}} & \makecell[tl]{This error code indicates that there is a problem communicating with the WiFi module.}\\
      \hline
      \makecell[tl]{img here} & \makecell[tl]{\textbf{Internal Storage Error}} & \makecell[tl]{This error code indicates that there is a problem reading the internal memory.}\\
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Maybe someone is able to give me a hint on how I can achieve what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the entry post with a MWE.

Comment: @Vulpecula Have a look at the `adjustbox` package and its `valign` key

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am trying it now, but I’m not sure where to place the adjustable box. Does it need to be in each single cell or do I span it over a full row?

Comment: Off-topic: Please replace `\begin{tabular*}{16cm}{p{3cm} p{4cm} p{9cm}}` with `\begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr16cm-4\tabcolsep\relax}{p{3cm} p{4cm} p{9cm}}`. Better still, replace it with `\begin{tabular}{@{} p{3cm} p{4cm} p{9cm} @{}}`, and replace `\end{tabular*}` with `\end{tabular}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move image baseline to its top. This can be simply done by use of the package `adjustbox` when images are included by `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}   % shortened
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % for "valign",  also load graphicx
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering 
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{25mm} >{\bfseries}l X}
      \toprule
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    & Battery Error &   This error code indicates that there is
                        a problem with the battery and/or the charging electronics. \\
                        
      \midrule
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    & GNSS Error    &   This error code indicates that there is
                        a problem communicating with the GNSS module.               \\
      \midrule
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    & Error         &   This error code indicates that there is
                        a problem communicating with either one or both of the inertial measurement units.                                          \\
      \midrule
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    & WiFi Error    &   This error code indicates that there is
                        a problem communicating with the WiFi module.               \\
      \midrule
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    & Internal Storage Error
                &   This error code indicates that there is
                    a problem reading the internal memory.                          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I would replace all `\midrule`s in table body with `\addlinespace`:

[image]

Unfortunately this solution doesn't work with `\includesvg` command of `svg` package. I hope that converting `.svg` images to `.pdf` will not make to much trouble to you.

Comment: Thank you Zarko, that solved my problem. Also, converting from SVG to PDF is not a problem.

Comment: @Vulpecula, super. Happy TeX-ing!